# Eslint with airbnb does not load when using .eslint.json

Tags: javascript, eslint, lint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm trying to setup linting for a node project. I wish to use the airbnb style guide.

These are my dev dependencies in package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2"
  }
```

###### This is my .eslintrc.json file:

```
  {
    "env": {
      "es2021": true,
      "node": true
    },    
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": "latest",
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "rules": { /* ... */ }
  }
```

I keep getting this error (in the VSCode Output terminal):

```
[Info  - 9:24:00] Failed to load config "airbnb" to extend from. Referenced from: C:\GitWorkspace\lorand.eu\backend\.eslintrc.json
```

Note that eslint works just fine whenever using .yml or .js files as configuration.

How could I solve this error in the json config file?

P.S While this is a minimal reproducible error, the setup process that yielded the error came by following the instructions in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SydnKbGc7W8&t=1111s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `eslint-config-airbnb-base` package via the command below...

```
  $ npm install --save-dev eslint-config-airbnb-base
```

...you have to add **"airbnb-base"** the following to your `.eslintrc.json` file's `extends` field, as seen below:

##### `"extends": "airbnb-base"`

---

The package `eslint-config-airbnb` that is installed via the command...

npm install --save-dev eslint-config-airbnb

...is the package that you use `"extends": "airbnb"` to your .eslintrc
file

---

The difference is that the latter, the `airbnb` supports react, where the `airbnb-base` does not.

Obviously, you don't want to add the unnecessary rules for a framework you're not using.