# What are the steps to activate airbnb's eslint rules in my svelte project?

Tags: typescript, eslint, sveltekit

I am trying to use Airbnb's eslint rules for my sveltekit project.

I have an `.eslintrc.ts` file that reads like:

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    extends: ["airbnb-base"],
    plugins: ["svelte3", "@typescript-eslint"],
    overrides: [{ files: ["**/*.svelte"], processor: "svelte3/svelte3" }],
    settings: {
        "svelte3/typescript": () => require("typescript"),
    },
    rules: {
        "no-new-object": true, // i tried to enable specific rules
    },
    parserOptions: {
        project: ["./tsconfig.json"],
    },
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es2017: true,
        node: true,
        jest: true,
    },
}
```

Why don't the rules work for me? Here is a breakage of a rule:

```
const x = new Object()
```

That violates [no-new-object](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#objects) but it doesnt give an error

Why isnt it working? I expect   `extends: ["airbnb-base"],` to give me access to all the rules. I also expect   `extends: ["airbnb"],` to give all rules. Neither works.

Here are some things Ive installed in my `package.json` dev dependencies:

```
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.54.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.54.1",
        "eslint": "^8.35.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.7.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^4.0.0",
```

I want to learn how to activate all the airbnb rules or activate them one by one, but there is no explanation of how to do this

I tried following [this](https://medium.com/@Tunmise/set-up-eslint-with-airbnb-style-guide-in-5-minutes-d7b4cc5707f8) and [this](https://dev.to/mhaecker/use-airbnb-s-eslint-config-with-typescript-prettier-in-svelte-apps-4fb7) but neither worked for me. I also closed a bunch of other research tabs that did not give me good results. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72582248/eslint-with-airbnb-does-not-load-when-using-eslint-json) also doesnt help

Edit: Currently it looks like the issue was that I had a `.eslintrc.cjs` duplicating eslint settings; the linter was looking at that file, not the one I expected it to look at. Deleting that .cjs file has me closer to resolving the issue; will likely close / delete this q if deleting the .cjs file fixes my problem

Comment: How are you running eslint?

Comment: `npx eslint . --ext .ts` <= currently gives a lot of warnings and errors, but they look wrong to me. For instance it says `warning  'describe' is not defined` about a test file, even though I have `import { describe, test, expect } from "vitest"` at the top. The goal rule isn't showing on `const x = new Object()` yet either

Answer (score 0):

Solution came when my coworker said to install `eslint-plugin-svelte`

[The page for it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-svelte) says "The eslint-plugin-svelte can not be used with the eslint-plugin-svelte3. If you are using eslint-plugin-svelte3 you need to remove it."

So i did that and installed `eslint-plugin-svelte` and changed my `.eslintrc.cjs` (which i started using instead of .ts) to read:

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    extends: ["airbnb", "airbnb-typescript", "airbnb-typescript/base", "plugin:svelte/recommended"],
    plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
    overrides: [{ files: ["**/*.svelte", "**/*.ts"] }],
    settings: {
        "svelte3/typescript": () => require("typescript"),
    },
    parserOptions: {
        project: ["./tsconfig.json"],
    },
    rules: {
        "no-new-object": 1,
    },
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es2017: true,

        node: true,
    },
}
```

Note that mentions of `svelte3` are removed.

Now `npx eslint . --ext .ts` shows 483 errors and `const x = new Object()` gives a warning `The object literal notation {} is preferable.eslintno-new-object)`

Victory